# Ruby on Rails Avatar Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I've been trying to work with Paperclip. I've installed ImageMagick. I've added the line 
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin" in config/initializers/paperclip.rb.

But i'm still getting the error "Avatar Paperclip::CommandNotFoundError".

How can i possibly solve this?

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have the rmagick gem in your Gemfile

```
gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick'
```

Next, open a rails console from the command line.

```
$ rails c
```

type:

```
`which convert`
```

You should see something like

```
=> "/usr/bin/convert\n"
```

If you do, then take the path, in this case `/usr/bin`, and set `Paperclip.options[:command_path]` to that path.  If you don't, you need to make sure that ImageMagick is installed.  For OSX use Homebrew (http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) or MacPorts. For Debian systems you'll need two packages:

```
imagemagick
libmagick9-dev
```

For Redhat/rpm-based systems, you can try their packages, but they are pretty old and you'll probably be better off compiling from source.

If you've got ImageMagick already installed then you'll need to make sure the `convert` command is in your path.

As a side note, if the rmagick gem installs, then you should have ImageMagick already installed, you just need to figure out where it is on your system.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried installing/using rMagic?

Answer (score 0):

I installed ImageMagick using the Binary from Macports for Snow Leopard. The install went fine, but Paperclip wasn't finding ImageMagick and I was getting the same errors.

I added the following to config/environments/development.rb:

```
   Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/local/bin"
```

I restarted the server and everything works perfectly.